# How to call summary value each fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<fieldset class="accessory">
   <legend>Premium</legend>
   Premium Soup 1 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">
   Premium Soup 2 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">  
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="accessory">
   <legend>Premium</legend>
   Chicken Rice 1 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="value_quantity">
   Chicken Rice 2 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="value_quantity"> 
   Chicken Rice 3 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity"> 
</fieldset>
```

This is my jquery:

```
$('.accessory').each(function (index, element) {
   var group_quantity = 0;
   $('.value_quantity').each(function (key, val){
      group_quantity = group_quantity + parseInt($(val).val());        
   });
   console.log("Group" + index + ':' + group_quantity);
});
```

I want result follow this:

```
Group 1 : 2
Group 2 : 5
```

But my script is incorrect. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider `this` context while iterating `.value_quantity` which will select only those elements which are `children` of the parent `.accessory` or else all the `.value_quantity` will get selected while manipulating.

> [**`jQuery( selector [, context ] )`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) *Accepts a string containing a `CSS selector` which is then used to match a set of `elements`. `context` is a `DOM Element`, `Document`, or `jQuery` to use as context.*

---

> The [**`.each()`**](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method is designed to make `DOM looping` constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the `DOM elements` that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, *the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element*, so the keyword **`this`** refers to the **element**.

```js
$('.accessory').each(function(index, element) {
  var group_quantity = 0;
  $('.value_quantity', this).each(function(key, val) {
    //_______________^^^^^^
    //OR $(this).find('.value_quantity').each(function...
    group_quantity = group_quantity + parseInt($(val).val());
  });
  console.log("Group" + index + ':' + group_quantity);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="accessory">
  <legend>Premium</legend>
  Premium Soup 1
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">Premium Soup 2
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="accessory">
  <legend>Premium</legend>
  Chicken Rice 1
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="value_quantity">Chicken Rice 2
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="value_quantity">Chicken Rice 3
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">
</fieldset>
```

**Simplified version:**

```js
$('.accessory').each(function(index, element) {
  var group_quantity = 0;
  $('.value_quantity', this).each(function() {
    group_quantity += +this.value;
  });
  console.log("Group" + index + ':' + group_quantity);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="accessory">
  <legend>Premium</legend>
  Premium Soup 1
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">Premium Soup 2
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="accessory">
  <legend>Premium</legend>
  Chicken Rice 1
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="value_quantity">Chicken Rice 2
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="value_quantity">Chicken Rice 3
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="value_quantity">
</fieldset>
```